# Converting financial information to pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, dictionary, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api, quantitative-finance

I am trying to get stock data such as balance_sheet, income_statement and cash_flow for multiple stocks and converting it to a data frame for manipulations.

here is the getting the data part of the code :

```
 **import yahoo_fin.stock_info as yfs
    tickers = ['AMZN','AAPL','MSFT','DIS','GOOG'] 
    balance_sheet=[]
    income_statement=[]
    cash_flow=[]
    balance_sheet.append({ticker : yfs.get_balance_sheet(ticker) for ticker in tickers})
    income_statement.append({ticker : yfs.get_income_statement(ticker) for ticker in tickers })
    cash_flow.append({ticker : yfs.get_cash_flow(ticker) for ticker in tickers})**
```

This part works well and returns a dictionary for each category. I then this :

**my_dict=cash_flow+balance_sheet+income_statement
dff=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='columns', dtype=None, columns=None)**

Note that when I try orient='index' I get the following error message :

**AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 my_dict=cash_flow+balance_sheet+income_statement
----> 2 dff=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index', dtype=None, columns=None)
3 # dff=dff.set_index('endDate')
4 dff
5 # cash_flow

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in from_dict(cls, data, orient, dtype, columns)
1361             if len(data) > 0:
1362                 # TODO speed up Series case
-> 1363                 if isinstance(list(data.values())[0], (Series, dict)):
1364                     data = _from_nested_dict(data)
1365                 else:

```
enter code here
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'**

If someone could let me know what I'm doing wrong that would be very appreciated ! :)